# JS Alert showing 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

**Hi there,**

I just moved from C#/C++ to JavaScript last night, and am loving it!

I've just come across some behavior that I don't understand, wondering if anyone can shed some light on it?

When I call this script, I'm getting the expected alert box showing '5.5', however after that box is closed I get another alert simply showing "undefined", can anyone shed any light on this?

**Code below:**

```
var myObj = {

age : 5,
weight : 5.5,

toString : function(){
    alert(this.weight);
}

}

alert(myObj.toString());
```

Many thanks

Comment: The fact that you have two `alert()` functions in your code might be a hint as to why you get two `alert` boxes ;)

Comment: The question wasn't why do I have two alerts... It was why is the second showing undefined, which has been answered now. Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code calls `alert()` twice.

The first alert is the one displaying `this.weight`. But then the second displays whatever value is returned from the `myObj.toString()` function, and since you've coded that function without an explicit return value it returns `undefined` by default.

Normally a `.toString()` function would actually return a string, so you should do this:

```
toString : function(){
    return this.weight.toString();
}
```

Then you'll just get the one alert, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/eph7x/

And indeed then you can simply use:

```
alert(myObj);
```

...because your custom `.toString()` will get called automatically.

Comment: ThankYou! I did originally call just myObj, didn't realize it'd call my toString automatically! Thanks for pointing out the return lol, getting a bit too carried away with not having to define types haha! Will accept answer when it becomes available.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding not having to define types, remember that JS does actually have different types, e.g., string, number, object - it's just that any variable can hold a value of any type.

Comment: Yeah I get that they're interpreted at run-time, which is pretty sweet! Still prefer strongly-typed though.